# How may I repeat this procedure n times?

Tags: function-construction

This is the procedure

```
      Do[With[{},mammamia = RandomReal[1, 9];
ClearAll[inexactSolve]
SetAttributes[inexactSolve, HoldFirst]
inexactSolve[expr_Solve] := 
 ReleaseHold@
   Replace[Hold[expr], a_?InexactNumberQ :> inert[ToString[a]], 
    Infinity] /. inert[a_String] :> ToExpression[a]

With[{A = 0.625, h = 0.61},
 s1 = mammamia[[1]];
 s2 = mammamia[[2]];
 st = mammamia[[3]];
 th1 = mammamia[[4]];
 th2 = mammamia[[5]];
 th3 = mammamia[[6]];
 gammai = mammamia[[7]];
 gammam = mammamia[[8]];
 gammao = mammamia[[9]];
 h1 = s1 h /2;
 h2 = s2 h/2;
 h3 = st h/2;
 azzo = inexactSolve@Solve[
    A == A1 + A2 + A3 &&
     th1 == b2/b1 &&
     th2 == b3/b2 &&

       th3 == bt/b3 &&
     A1 == h1 (b1 + b2)/2 &&

     A2 == h2 (b2 + b3)/2 &&
     A3 == (h - h1 - h2) (b3 + bt)/2 
    , {A1, A2, A3, b2, b1, b3, bt}];
 Flatten[{h1, h2, h3, gammai, gammai, gammao, azzo[[1]][[;; , 2]]}]
 ]],100]
```

I tried with `'Do'` but I receive an error: `'Tag Times in Null\ Null\ inexactSolve[expr_Solve] is Protected.`'

Comment: Without your actual code, we cannot help you finding the error. However, perhaps `Table` or similar constructs would be simpler to use, but at the moment it is unclear what exactly you intend.

Comment: This is my actual code. If you copy and paste it on a notebook, it should run.

Comment: You are commenting on a `Do`, which is not present here.

Comment: I've added the "Do" instruction.

Comment: You are missing three `;`s : at the end of line 2, end of line 3 and after `ToExpression[a]`. Plus, I don't see any reason to put the function def inside `Do`, and your `inert` is not defined.

Comment: Happy Fish, if I add the dotted commas I don't receive any output.

Comment: And you should `Print` your result in the last line, `Do` only returns `Null`

Comment: I didn't know that. Can I try something different to not print results? I need the results to be readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment. You can try this. `res` will contain a list of you 100 result.

```
ClearAll[inexactSolve] ; SetAttributes[inexactSolve, HoldFirst] ; 
inexactSolve[expr_Solve] := 
ReleaseHold@
Replace[Hold[expr], a_?InexactNumberQ :> inert[ToString[a]], 
Infinity] /. inert[a_String] :> ToExpression[a]; 

res = Reap@Do[
With[{A = 0.625, h = 0.61}, mammamia = RandomReal[1, 9]; 
 s1 = mammamia[[1]];
 s2 = mammamia[[2]];
 st = mammamia[[3]];
 th1 = mammamia[[4]];
 th2 = mammamia[[5]];
 th3 = mammamia[[6]];
 gammai = mammamia[[7]];
 gammam = mammamia[[8]];
 gammao = mammamia[[9]];
 h1 = s1 h/2;
 h2 = s2 h/2;
 h3 = st h/2;
 azzo = 
  inexactSolve@
   Solve[A == A1 + A2 + A3 && th1 == b2/b1 && th2 == b3/b2 && 
     th3 == bt/b3 && A1 == h1 (b1 + b2)/2 && 
     A2 == h2 (b2 + b3)/2 && A3 == (h - h1 - h2) (b3 + bt)/2, {A1,
      A2, A3, b2, b1, b3, bt}];
 Sow@Flatten[{h1, h2, h3, gammai, gammai, gammao, 
    azzo[[1]][[;; , 2]]}]], 100] // Last // First
```

Comment: This might be too long, but it is exactly what I wanted!!